# Click and hold doesn't work. Selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, click, drag

I'm using selenium webdriver + python. I have a problem with "click and hold" method. Click is working. But "hold" isn't. Eventually i can't drang and drop element. ("drag and drop" method from selenium docs. doesn't work never consequently i dont use it.) I have already use drag and drop helper.js and a lot of varied things. Nothing doesn't works.
This script perfectly working to another simmilar project. What's wrong?
I see, that element was clickked but instantly dropped. Without hold and move.

```
sourceEle = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'source')
targetEle = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'target')
targetEleXOffset = targetEle.location.get("x")
targetEleYOffset = targetEle.location.get("y")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(sourceEle).pause(1).perform()
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(sourceEle).pause(1).perform()
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(targetEleXOffset, targetEleYOffset).perform()
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(targetEle).perform()
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(targetEleXOffset, targetEleYOffset).pause(1).perform()
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).release().perform()
```